# Category Filtering with Ajax on WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, categories

When I select the cateogries the posts don't filter by category/taxonomy - all the posts just stay present on the page.

I've tried to debug but with no luck. Any help would be much appreicated!

Here's also the github link with my project files: https://github.com/guyku/WordPressAjax_RyanMcGovern_Lesson

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

  <body>

    <div id="content">
     <?php include('content.php'); ?>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**content.php:**

```
<div class="js-filter">
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if($query->have_posts()) :
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
                the_content('<p>', '</p>');
            endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>

<div class="categories">
    <ul>
        <li class="js-filter-item"><a href="<?= home_url(); ?>">All</a></li>
<?php 
$cat_args = array(
    'exclude' => array(1),
    'option_all' => 'All'
);

$categories = get_categories($cat_args);

foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
    <li class="js-filter-item"><a data-category="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>" href="<?= get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?= $cat->name; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**scripts.js:**

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var category = $(this).data('category');

            $.ajax({
                url:wp_ajax.ajax_url,
                data: { action: 'filter', category: category },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('.js-filter').html(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    console.warn(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**scripts.php:**

```
<?php
/*
* Enqueue scripts.js if file scripts.js exists
*/
function load_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . 'scripts.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

    wp_localize_script('ajax' , 'wp_ajax',
        array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
        );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

?>
```

**example.php:**

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax' );

function filter_ajax() {


$category = $_POST['category'];

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        );

if(isset($category)) {
    $args['category__in'] = array($category);
}

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if($query->have_posts()) :
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
                the_content('<p>', '</p>');
            endwhile;
        endif;
            wp_reset_postdata(); 


    die();
}
?>
```

**functions.php:**

```
<?php

require_once('scripts.php');
require_once('example.php');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in you file content.php

you will have to add your category name
$args = array(

```
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'category_name' => 'Your_Category_Name'
    );
```